# I wnat to retain the value of "Spins Left" even after refreshing the browser in javascript

Tags: javascript

We have a Spin Wheel and the user can spin only 3 times. And we have displayed "Spins Left: 3" before the user starts spinning the wheel.

If user spins the wheel for the first time, then it displays "Spins Left:2".

Now, if the user refreshes the page after the first spin, the "Spins Left" should be 2 only. But it shows the value 3.

Can anyone please help on acheiving this?

Comment: You can use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Also, please provide what you have tried so far when you ask a question. Have a look at [How to ask questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage:

`var spins = localStorage.get('spins') || 0`

`localStorage.setItem('spins', spins)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage